# create trigger insert records to table after another 3 tables got new row records

Tags: postgresql

I have 4 tables. named a, b, c and d

I created procedure join from parts of column table a, b, c and then insert into table d. this is query for example

```
 insert into d (id,1,2,3,4)
select a.1, b.2, b.3, c.4
from a a
join b b
on a.id = b.id
join c c
on b.id = c.id;
```

how to create trigger when all of those 3 tables got new row and then we execute that query proc. so if just only 1 or 2 tables got new row, the trigger wont start

i want to create trigger something like this

```
CREATE TRIGGER data_result
  AFTER INSERT
  ON a, b, c
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE data_integration();
```

thank you for help

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe oh ok edited. so i must created 3 trigger after insert for each of the table?

Comment: Right, that's what you have to do.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe hmmm sorry i dont get it. so there will be 3 same records on d tables, if i create 3 trigger to run that query. because query will run 3 times.

Comment: Each of the triggers would have to query the other tables. But there will always be a race condition if two inserts happen at the same time. No, there is no good way to do that. Perhaps you can elaborate a bit and tell us what problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe yah, like i said i want to create trigger when those 3 table got new row record then will insert into table d. i created the join query insert into table d, but i want to run that query automatically with that condition (if 3 tables got new records)

Comment: Yes, but **why** do you want to do that?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe finally i solved it. i added 1 column more in table d for status. in default status is 'no'. then in my function i added function where status is 'no'. after that i added update status set 'yes'